# What type of ListView is this?

Tags: android-layout, listview, android

What kind of list view is in this navigation drawer? It has two sections. One with Inbox, starred, sent mail, drafts and the other with all mail, trash, spam & follow up.

So is it a sectional ListView without section headers or are these two ListViews?

[image]

Found the image here: http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-standard-styles

Comment: Could be anything. Could even be simple textviews in a layout. How are we supposed to tell you from looking at a picture?

Comment: What's the name of the app? If it is open source just look in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email/).

Comment: Its a design pattern that I've seen in several apps. So I'm guessing it might be something like a sectional list view

Comment: @user3249477 we could figure it out here. Isn't this awesome website for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Google offers I/O 2014 app source code as Material Design sample code

The Google I/O 2014 app has successfully lived up to its initial purpose of providing scheduling for Google I/O attendees and allowing us at home to check in and watch the keynote presentation, as well as other live-streamed sessions. But what happens to the app now?

Instead of leaving the app to be forgotten in the Google Play Store, Google has decided to use the app as a shining light for developers. Google updated the I/O 2014 app with Material Design and the Android L developer preview before making the full source code free and available for developers to download and utilize as a template for their own apps.

Although the majority of actual benefits of the Google I/O 2014 app were only good during the two days of conference back in June, the app now offers developers examples of a number of features and techniques. Developers can look forward to sample code for:

```
Google Drive API
Google Cloud Messaging
Android L developer preview
Android Wear
Video streaming
Reminders and alarms
NFC scanning and beaming
Feedback mechanisms
```

In addition to simply just dropping the code on developers, there is also some reference material available on the project git page, expect also to see video tutorials coming soon through the developer channel.

Once you’ve got your Android L device or emulator up and rolling, grab the source code for the Google I/O 2014 app from the GitHub page and get on building your own Material Design apps.

[GITHUB CODE](https://github.com/google/iosched)

[image]

---

maybe this is what you are looking for

https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/lpreview/res/layout-v21

Comment: The 2nd link is broken. But I found it. https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/navdrawer.xml . There are 2 linear layouts but here are three sections https://lh6.ggpht.com/qKyr23paaa6jnqMA7IpEBojqvUjIJrJX56-LzxZZ3Q-Qo1IQ8qRwosjrxt1jTBBFEHY=h900-rw